# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax - RANK FUNCTION

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, rank

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY `point`) FROM `user`
```

This is my query, I excute it in phpmyadmin, and receive the message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY `point`) FROM `user` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"

I try to find the error but just can't.
Please help me!

Comment: MariaDB doesn't support window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB doesn't support window functions.  You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
        FROM user u2
        WHERE u2.point < u.point
       ) as rank
FROM `user` u;
```

Comment: Thank you very muck! It's run.